# How is 'ci' or 'ce' syllable pronounced in Italian?

Tags: regional, pronunciation

According to a book I read *ci* is pronounced *chi*. I don't know if it's my hearing but why do I hear *sh* in the TV show Gomorra? Is there an *sh* regional variant maybe?

Comment: Can you link to a specific example of audio with this pronunciation? "ci" and "ce" can be pronounced with a short "sh" sound in some regional varieties of Italian (e.g. [Tuscan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tuscan_dialect#Weakening_of_G_and_C)).

Comment: It looks like "sh" is a variant that exists in the [Neapolitan language also](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neapolitan_language#Consonants). That might be relevant to your example since it looks like Gomorra is set in Naples

Comment: Welcome to Italian.SE!

Comment: By “chi” do you mean “chi” as it would be pronounced in English (for instance in “chill”)?

Answer (score 4):

The standard pronunciation of Italian *ci* (unless there is a *s* before it) is /tʃi/ (which is approximately like the initial sounds of English word “cheap”). In some regional variants (Tuscany, Lazio, parts of Southern Italy) it is quite usual to pronounce it, only when it follows a vowel, like /ʃi/ (the initial sound of “sheen”, say).

The same applies to *ce* (standard pronunciation with /tʃ/, regional pronunciation after a vowel with /ʃ/).

The regional sound is similar to that which in standard Italian is denoted by *sci* (or *sce*), the difference being that in the latter the /ʃ/-sound, after a vowel, is geminated (i.e. stronger, doubled). For instance, the standard pronunciation of the word *pece* (“pitch”, the substance) is /'petʃe/, its regional pronunciation can be /'peʃe/, while the word *pesce* (“fish”) is pronounced mostly everywhere /ˈpeʃːe/ (also denoted /ˈpeʃʃe/).

Comment: Are you sure about the last sentence? I think that in Northern Italy (i.e. above the La Spezia-Rimini line) the sound /ʃ/ is normally not geminated (certainly not in my pronunciation)

Comment: @DenisNardin: I'm not sure of anything. :) Do you pronounce _pesce_ /'peʃe/? I never heard anything but /ˈpeʃːe/, but I can't vouch for the whole of Italy. I'm not at all a fan of Forvo but, just to be sure we are saying the same thing, all of those are geminated pronunciations: https://forvo.com/word/pesce/#it

Comment: I don't want to be too assertive, but I can certainly do two pronunciation, one with the /ʃ/ stronger than the other, and my normal one is the weaker one. Mine is probably closest to the one by Nottedinverno in Forvo. Remember that geminate consonants do not exist in the regional languages of Northern Italy and that when Italian was taught in school after the Unification people improvised their pronunciation based on the written form, so often non-indicated geminates were not geminated in the regional pronunciation (the case of *z*s is emblematic).

Comment: I see. To my ear, Nottedinverno's is still a geminated pronunciation: you should hear how a Roman says “pece”... :)